# Write 2-channel array of shorts to WAV file

Tags: java, audio

I have 2 arrays of shorts containing musical data, one for each channel, and I need the simplest Java method/library possible to write them to a WAV file without the fuss with headers. Does anyone know of such a method/library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Sound can write WAV files. You may find what you are looking for here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/sound/programmer_guide/chapter7.html#a114602

Not sure if it takes shorts as I have only used it to playback files not save them.

Comment: So what are my options if It doesn't take shorts?

Comment: I have used the code given in this section to save wav files. The shorts have to be converted to constituent bytes that abide by the audio format you are using in your wav file. I assume you are saving to 16-bit encoding. Each short is converted to two bytes and their order in the outgoing data stream depends on whether your format is little- or big-endian.